# Has this series for $\ln(2)$ been discovered yet?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, logarithms, math-history

$$\ln(2)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{12}-\frac{1}{13}+...$$
This is something I came up with and was intrigued, and no this isn't random; there's a pattern to this.

Since you guys are asking for a relation, here it is;
$$\ln(2)=1+\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{(-1)^{S_n-1}}{S_n-1} $$

Where $S_n$ is the $n$-th number that is not a perfect power ([A007916](https://oeis.org/A007916), and $S_1$ is $2$). Proof to this is also somewhat easy to derive.

Comment: What's the pattern?

Comment: If you're going to ask about a series but think the pattern is unrecognizable enough at a glance that you're inclined to specify "no, this isn't random," it would improve your chances of getting a useful answer if you actually stated what the pattern is.

Comment: The least obscure instance in the OEIS the sequence of denominators in the given series is probably https://oeis.org/A143070: "A positive integer n is included if the number of 0's in the binary representation of n is a power of 2 (including being possibly 1)." In any case one would need to specify the pattern of signs, too.

Comment: @Travis I have noticed it right after I had posted my comment. Nevertheless thanks for your hint.

Comment: You are stating this like a puzzle, not a math problem.

Comment: I recommend including your proof in an edit. It might help narrow the literature search for your result.

Comment: I've added in the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Equivalently, the problem is to compute $L=\sum_{s\in S}(-1)^s/(s-1)$ where $S$ is the set of all perfect powers. A similar problem of computing $\sum_{s\in S}1/(s-1)\color{gray}{[{}=1]}$ goes back to [Goldbach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Goldbach) as far as I know.

The idea is pretty much the same. Let $N$ be the set of all integers (strictly) greater than $1$. Then each $s\in S$ has a representation $s=a^n$ with unique $a\in N\setminus S$ and $n\in N$; the same is true for $s\in N$ if we also allow $n=1$. Hence (each of the series below is absolutely convergent)
\begin{align}
L&=\sum_{a\in N\setminus S}(-1)^a\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^n-1}\\&=\sum_{a\in N\setminus S}(-1)^a\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a^{-nk}\\&=\sum_{a\in N\setminus S}(-1)^a\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^k(a^k-1)}\\&=\sum_{s\in N}\frac{(-1)^s}{s(s-1)}=2\ln 2-1.
\end{align}
[The sum in the question is $1+\sum_{s\in N\setminus S}(-1)^{s-1}/(s-1)=1-(\ln 2-L)$.]